# Need help in computing perfect numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to compute perfect numbers. This is my current code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  int num = 0;
  int badness;
  for(int i=2; i<10000; i++)
  { 
    for (int j = 1; j<i; j++)
    { 
      if (i % j == 0)
      {
        num += j;
      }
    }

    if(num %i ==0)
    {
      cout << i << endl;
    } 

    num = 0;
  }
return 0;
```

}

The output I am getting is

```
6
28
120
496
672
8128
```

However my desired output is to get:

```
6 28 496 8128
```

Which are the perfect numbers in my range specified (i.e. 10000).

Comment: BTW: get rid of _//Start of_ and _//End of..._

Comment: Its just helps me with my code thats all

Comment: Please explain the motivation for your code. Otherwise, the solution to your question is a one line response: `cout<<"6 28";`

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What is your code supposed to do? Right now `cout << "6 28" << endl;` would be a solution to the problem you described, but obviously that's not what you want.

Comment: Not completely clear what you want, but if it is about getting values at 1 line why is the `<< endl` in the loop?

Comment: Where is 'candidate' declared, type and initial value?

Comment: if you don't want a new line, then don't push `endl` to `cout`. if you want fewer numbers, reduce the limit you iterate `i` to -- you currently don't use `badness` and `candidate` doesn't seem to be declared... you never change the value of `num` so.... what's your actual code?

Comment: `num` is never increased so `num % i` will never result in anything useful, as well your last `num = 0` indentation is incorrect. Please fix code and specify question more clearly. As well `badness` is never used, `i` is used outside of scope. `candidate` is not declared. Your code has many issues.

Comment: oh so sorry it needs to print perfect numbers (badness 0) up to values less than 10000, separated by a single space. For example quitegood 100 should print 6 28. and candidate was supposed to be num sorry

Comment: What constitutes a perfect number?

Comment: an integer that is equal to the sum of its divisors

Comment: Add this information back into the question under an edit. This will help others provide useful information to you, also fix up your code, variable names, indentation and anything else.

Comment: Ok thanks iv done that

Answer (score 6):

From Wiki:

> In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors, that is, the sum of its positive divisors excluding the number itself

Therefore you have to change

```
if(num %i ==0)
```

to

```
if(num == i)
```

You want to check if the sum is equal to the number itsself, not if the sum and the numbers modulus is zero.

In order to print them on the same line you will have to change

```
cout << i << endl;
```

to

```
cout << i << '\t';
```

and before returning from main

```
cout << endl;
```

which then yields the output:

```
6       28      496     8128
```